# Remove a file from a ZIP archive using JclCompression in Delphi XE2

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, jedi-code-library

I've got this situation where I need to remove a specific file from a ZIP archive. Within the application all handling of ZIP files is done using JclCompression. I was wondering if any of you know how to remove a specific file from a ZIP archive using JclCompression? (I couldn't find it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I just accidentally ran into the solution:

Besides the `TJclZipCompressionArchive` and `TJclDecompressionArchive` the JclCompression library also provides a `TJclZipUpdateArchive` class. This class contains a method to remove a file from the archive.

```
zip.RemoveItem(PackedName);
```